# String formatting python

Tags: python, string, locale

I am trying to understand what option value `n` exactly does in string formatting for the `type` flag.

[PEP 3101](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) says (in the section on available integer types):

```
'n' - Number. This is the same as 'd', except that it uses the
              current locale setting to insert the appropriate
              number separator characters.
```

I tried the following code:

```
print "This is a large number with formatting applied: {0:n}".format(1384309238430)
```

I get the output:

```
This is a large number with formatting applied: 1384309238430
```

That is, no number separator characters are present. How do I find my locale setting? How do I get the number separator characters (I am thinking that by number separator characters, it is referring to things such as thousands separator commas).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')
print('{0:n}'.format(1234))
```

yields

```
1,234
```

You can find your current locale with `locale.getlocale()`:

```
In [31]: locale.getlocale()
Out[31]: ('en_US', 'UTF8')
```

and the default locale with `locale.getdefaultlocale()`.

On *nix systems, you can get a list of locales your machine is aware of with the command `locale -a`.

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on the locale:

```
>>> print "{0:n}".format(134.3)
134.3
>>> import locale
>>> locale.getlocale()
(None, None)
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE')
'de_DE'
>>> print "{0:n}".format(134.3)
134,3
>>> print "{0:n}".format(13423.3)
13423,3
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')
'en_US.UTF-8'
>>> print "{0:n}".format(13423.3)
13,423.3
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [`locale`](http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html) module. The [`getdefaultlocale`](http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html#locale.getdefaultlocale) method is of interest if you want to just default to your normal system settings.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call [`setlocale`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/module-locale.html), probably with an empty string for the `locale` parameter.